# Citrix Workplace not starting

Tags: 23.10, citrix

I downloaded and installed [Citrix Workspace app 2311 for Linux](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html).
I see it in the programs (via windows key --> type citrix)
Unfortunately it does not start.

In var/log/syslog I see the following error:

`/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/selfservice: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

However if found this library in `/snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37`

**How to fix this error?**

**Work around**

```
sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18
sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.70 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.70
sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70
sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.70 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.70

sudo ln -s /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are messing around with symlinks and shared libraries when you could simply do this:

```bash
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

The other libraries files will be installed together. Somehow the icaclient package lists a bunch of required dependencies as only "Recommended" possibly for compatibility, so you could have tried `sudo apt install --install-recommends ./icaclient_23.11.0.82_amd64.deb` or manually installed them. Anyway, the EULA window shows up, but 23.10 isn't officially supported.